# Ubuntu is slow on netbook, running on flash drive. Will this persist on a full install?

Tags: 13.04, ubuntu-netbook

I got a new Asus Eee PC 1025C Flare (Intel Atom, 2GB RAM) so I loaded Ubuntu 13.04 on a flash drive and tried to boot from there. And it was SLOW. it takes about 10 seconds to load the dashboard, and even longer to do anything else.

I tried tweaking it using compizconfig, but it's still slow. I can't do a full install yet because the laptop is still under the 1-week-factory-defect warranty. Will Ubuntu still be this slow once I do a full install? Should I use X/Lubuntu instead? (I'd rather not since I quite like Unity)

ps: I have some experience with Ubuntu; I used it on a bigger laptop and I love it. The Windows Starter that came with the laptop is running fine, but I'd rather have Ubuntu with this thing.

Comment: My guess is that it will be slow with a full install as well. +1 to trying k/x/or lubuntu.

Comment: I have an Atom with 2GB ram. Unity ran fine with 12.10; but after moving 13.04,Unity ran ok, but was just slow enough that I switched to Lubuntu. Your chip is more powerful than mine (N455), though. You might want to try it out for a few days, but x/l will probably be better.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a high-end computer, so it will not act like one. Video production is not in your future, at least not on this little guy. But reading from an internal hard drive will be faster than reading from a USB 2.0 flash drive. Anyone who's every seen Ubuntu running off a Live USB or CD while preparing to install has seen the difference between that that the speed after installing and rebooting to the hard drive.

My daughter runs 13.04 on an old Acer Aspire One netbook with an Atom and 1 GB, and it runs well enough. She uses LibreOffice, MuseScore, Firefox, Skye, and the like just fine. If you need more snap than you get with Ubuntu, you could try Lubuntu. It's much better on light-weight hardware.

Comment: > no video production. haha i was expecting that. D: // > what's the difference between Lubuntu and Xubuntu, anyway? Is on of them faster than the other? Because I started downloading Xubuntu last night; will try it on a Live USB later. also, can I still use programs from the Ubuntu software center if I go L/Xubuntu? I need to use TexWorks and everything that comes along with it. and Opera.

Comment: The only difference between Lubuntu and Xubuntu is that Lubuntu is based on the LXDE desktop while Xbuntu uses Xfce. Both are lighter on the system requirements than Ubuntu. It's like boxers vs. briefs. There isn't a "better", just a preference for one over the other. You'd really have to try both to know, but you might find Xubuntu fits your needs well enough that you won't bother trying the other. And yes, you can use programs from the Ubuntu software center, but they may have a lot of dependencies to be installed (automagically).

Comment: installed xubuntu and loving it. because ubuntu is just too slow. thank you! :)